# How can I fix this SSH hostname tab completion script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, autocomplete

I [found the following script](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080317085050719) (for bash) that enables me to get tab completion for any hostname I've connected to (from `~/.ssh/known_hosts`):

```
complete -W "$(echo `cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | sed -e s/,.*//g | uniq | grep -v "\["`;)" ssh
```

However, the problem is that the tab completion doesn't work after I've typed a username.

How can I improve this so if I type...

```
ssh myusername@my
```

and expect it to complete "myhostname.com" it will be able to do so?

It would be even better if it could tab whole strings (user@hostname) as well, but I can live with either option.  Without the first, this isn't much use unless my host username matches the local username.

Comment: Haven't we all learned in school to frown upon backticks, unless visiting a Unix museum, and that `$()` can be nested?! :) Still +1

Comment: @0xC0000022L Eek, sorry, I was much newer at bash when I wrote this question.

Answer (score 3):

The known_hosts file by default usually contains hashed entries which bash_completion can't parse.

You can edit your ssh_config (/etc/ssh/ssh_config) to set:

```
HashKnownHosts no
```

Then you'll probably need to clear your current known hosts file:

```
> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$COMP_WORDBREAKS` contains "@" (that is the default on my system) then serious problems arise which I could not solve (after pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> one "@" was removed).

But if you delete it from that environment variable then this works:

```
_foo () {
  if [[ "$COMP_WORDBREAKS" =~ "@" ]]; then
    echo ""
    echo '$COMP_WORDBREAKS contains "@"; aborting'
    COMPREPLY=()
  else
    at_in=no
    if [[ ${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]} =~ "@" ]]; then
      var="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
      tail="${var#*@}"
      prefix="${var%"$tail"}"
    else
      prefix=""
    fi
    COMPREPLY=($(cut -f 1 -d ' ' <~/.ssh/known_hosts |
      sed -e 's/,/\n/g' | uniq |
      awk -v prefix="${prefix}" '/\[/ {next}; {print prefix $0;}'))
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${COMPREPLY[*]}" "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"))
  fi
}

complete -F _foo ssh
```

Comment: It is an odd interaction, but it *only* applies to `@` not other characters in `COMP_WORDBREAKS` like `=`. @ is a readline special too, I suspect it may be so that the completion works the same way as with readline (C-x @) which preserves a leading @ if present. Alt workaround is  to check if `${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}` contains only "@" and use `compgen ... -P @`  to prefix it to the generated completions. *bash-completion* works around this with "`shopt -u hostcomplete`" which does other internal things but also removes "@" from `COMP_WORDBREAKS`.